# Is "follow their actions" semantically correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning, idiomatic-language

It doesn't sound idiomatic, but semantically it doesn't sound incorrect.

The verb follow can have the following meaning:

> To take as a model or precedent; imitate: followed my example and
>   resigned.

Therefore, you can say "follow his actions". Or is it the case. I usually see things like "follow their lead", "follow their example", "follow them", but "follow their actions" is usually meant as "observe their actions".

So can we say:

> Don't just imitate people, don't just follow their actions, follow
>   their beliefs, do whatever you want to do, believe in what you
>   believe.

It really doesn't sound right, because people don't use it like that, but seems to be semantically correct.

Comment: *I'm going to walk through this room full of traps now. Follow my actions (exactly), if you want to survive.* It sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short answer, as there's really nothing extra to say (and @Jason Bassford already answered in a comment).

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your use of 'follow their actions'.

Separate issue: your sentence is a little ambiguous as written.

I read

> ... don't just follow their actions, follow their beliefs.

as

> ... don't just follow their actions. *DO* follow their beliefs.

On a second reading, I don't think that's what you mean. I think you mean 'don't just follow their actions AND/OR beliefs'. You need some sort of conjunction to clarify the meaning. While there are occasions where, as a matter mainly of literary style, you can omit conjunctions, you can only do it when it does not introduce ambiguity.

> I could not understand his philosophy, his fundamental belief system.

In the sentence above I have omitted a conjunction, and it is acceptable. There is no ambiguity, and 'his fundamental belief system' is expanding on 'his philosophy'.

In your sentence I think you need a conjunction, and arguably to split the sentence clearly into two contrasting parts with a full-stop or semi-colon.

> Don't just imitate people, don't just follow their actions and beliefs; do whatever you want to do, believe in what you believe.

Answer (score 1):

While "follow his actions" is semantically correct, and certainly something you *can* say, it may not be the most *idiomatic* way to express this idea.  The more common expression "follow his *example*" seems to cover the situation you describe, since "example" is usually interpreted to mean "what they do".

> Mother:  Look at your brother!  He doesn't go out with his friends every night -- no, he stays home and studies!  You should **follow his example**

Another common expression is "do what they do" (or "don't do what they do").

> Think of the mindless legions who spend their lives in the empty pursuit of *stuff.  **Don't do what they do**.  If you are to work, at least work for something meaningful to you.

Although there is a certain amount of irony in telling people not to do what people tell them to do, as satirized in [this scene from Monty Python's 1979 film *Life of Brian*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVygqjyS4CA), but that's a different topic.

This is how I might phrase your sentence:

> Don't just imitate people; don't just do what they do, or believe what they believe.  Do what you want to do, and believe what you want to believe.